# Spring integration Java config without Java 8

Tags: spring, integration, java-7, dsl

We are adding Spring Integration to our project. The platform is Java 7 and migration to 8 is not planned in near future. All Spring configurations are Java configurations, no xml. 
But we can't find any guide to configure Spring Integration with pure Java but without lambdas etc. For example, we need Java 7 equivalent to something like this (sample from spring-integration-extensions github):

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow pollingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource(), 
                c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(100).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .transform(new ObjectToJsonTransformer())
            .channel("furtherProcessChannel")
            .get();
}
```

We are even not trained with new features of Java 8 to understand this. 
Is it a real deadlock for us, forcing migration to java 8 or using Spring integration xml config? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(100).maxMessagesPerPoll(1))` is an equivalent of:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource(), 
  new EndpointConfigurer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec>() {
    @Override
    public void configure(SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec c) {
        c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(100).maxMessagesPerPoll(1));
    }
  })
```

Any Lambda is just an inline interface implementation, so, what you need to do in your IDE just type `new` and press `CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE` - and IDE suggests you an appropriate implementation.

That's all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, that's exactly what we need.

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work with Java 7 even after successful configuration/build. The Runtime error on deployment is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/integration/dsl/support/EndpointConfigurer : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: Eh... Sorry. That was my fault. It has beed fixed recently and will be released as M3 tomorrow. However you can try it already with the latest snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the official Spring framework reference guide.

[This](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java) is the specific section your question pertains to.

Comment: Thank you. We know Spring Java Configuration already and use it widely. But we are new to Spring Integration, and not able to find examples of Java configurations for Spring Integration chains (without Java 8 features). It is not clear how to instantiate poller and bind it to channel in pure Java 7, for example.